# Create a Google Cloud Pub/Sub subscription for a Bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I am not finding a lot informations about this I would like to create a `Pub/Sub subscription` whenever there is a change in a `csv` file called `numbers.csv` stored in a GCP bucket called `my_storage`. I am able to create a cloud pub-sub but only to send a message for specific intervals but not based on any event. How can I set that Pub/Sub in order to just get a message when there is a change in my bucket? thanks. I read the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) but it's confusing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To receive a Pub/Sub notification whenever gs://your-bucket/numbers.csv is overwritten, use this command:

```
gsutil notification create -f json \
    -t projects/your-project/topics/your-pubsub-topic \
    -e OBJECT_FINALIZE \
    -p path/to/numbers.csv \
    gs://your-bucket-name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the official documentation:

[Using Pub/Sub notifications for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes)

Please follow the prerequisites steps from the documentation and then apply a notification configuration.

> The following steps add a notification configuration to your bucket
> that sends notifications for all supported events.
>
> `gsutil notification create -t TOPIC_NAME -f json gs://BUCKET_NAME`
>
> To send notifications for a subset of events, include the **-e flag.**

The supported events are:

```
OBJECT_FINALIZE 
OBJECT_METADATA_UPDATE
OBJECT_DELETE   
OBJECT_ARCHIVE
```

**Edit**

Example:
[notification - Configure object change notification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/notification)

Create a notification config that only sends an event when a new object has been created:

`gsutil notification create -f json -t TOPIC_NAME -e OBJECT_FINALIZE gs://example-bucket`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also read that documentation but it was not really clear for me. Where do I add the "-e" flag? And where do I specify which events from your list I want to use? thanks